# How to mock "this" keyword in Jest Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, this, jestjs

I need to this code using Jest Unit Testing:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.socialMediaId !== this.props.socialMediaId) {
      if (typeof this.window.FB !== 'undefined') {
        this.window.FB.XFBML.parse();
      }
    }
  }
```

using the test case:

```
it('should test componentDidUpdate', () => {
    props.socialMediaId = '/old_id/';
    const component = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    this.window.FB = {
      XFBML: {
        parse: () => {}
      }
    };
    props.socialMediaId = '/new_id/';
    component.setProps(props);
    expect(this.window.FB.XFBML.parse).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But, I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'window' of undefined

How to fix this issue with "**this**" keyword in this case?

Comment: Are you setting `window` on your component? Try `window.FB.XFBML.parse()` and `window.FB = { ... }`

Comment: I need to use `this.window` (due to iframe inside iframe issue) in my component as shared in the method `componentDidUpdate`. So, without changing the code in `componentDidUpdate`, how can I test that code?

Comment: It's going to be really hard to emulate that environment in tests. This feels like a design issue. Maybe add a `parseXFBML` prop to MyComponent & delegate dealing with `this.window.FB` weirdness to some glue code

Comment: It won't be possible, since, this component itself is loading the `FB script`, which add that object inside the `window` object.

Comment: Consider posting the component you're testing for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `this.window` is component property that is likely used as an abstraction over `window` global. `this` inside `componentDidUpdate` isn't the same object as `this` inside a test

It can be mocked on component instance:

```
const component = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
component.instance().window = { FB: {
  XFBML: {
    parse: jest.fn()
  }
} };
```

As a rule of thumb, all no-op functions should be Jest stubs for testability purposes, so their calls could be asserted later if needed.

Comment: `instance()` was what I was missing. Thanks a lot, @estus

Comment: I think you need `jest.fn()` or `jest.spyOn()`, `jest.spy()` doesn't seem to be a valid jest method.

Comment: @Azar Indeed. That was a typo, thanks for noticing.